# Extract Location Coordinates from JSON results

Tags: python, json, pandas, geocoding

I am using geocodio to derive coordinates from a list of 2272 addresses from my dataframe. When I try to flatten the results using json_normalize, I get coordinates but my dataframe is 4800+ rows instead of the correct 2272 for each address.

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize  
  
addys = json_normalize(locations, record_path=['results'])
addys = addys[['location']]
```

The resulting JSON output is as follows: (I only want the lat/lon coordinates for each address under the 'results' -- 'location' section for each entry)

```
[{'input': {'address_components': {'number': '3704',
    'predirectional': 'N',
    'street': 'Western',
    ...
    'zip': '73118',
    'country': 'US'},
   'formatted_address': '3704 N Western, Oklahoma City, OK 73118'},
  'results': [{'address_components': {'number': '3704',
     'predirectional': 'N',
     'street': 'Western',
     ...
     'zip': '73118',
     'country': 'US'},
    'formatted_address': '3704 N Western Ave, Oklahoma City, OK 73118',
    'location': {'lat': 35.507996, 'lng': -97.52952},
    ...
    'source': 'Oklahoma'},
   {'address_components': {'number': '3704',
     'predirectional': 'N',
     'street': 'Western',
     ...
     'country': 'US'},
    'formatted_address': '3704 N Western Ave, Oklahoma City, OK 73118',
    'location': {'lat': 35.508013, 'lng': -97.529453},
    ...
    'source': 'Acog Counties'}]},
 {'input': {'address_components': {'number': '1503',
    'street': 'Winding Ridge',
```

Comment: Final shape (addys.shape) returns 4882, 1

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to go down your dictionary. Like this:

```
import json

data = json.loads('{"a":{"b":{"location": {"lat": 35.507996, "lng": -97.52952}}}}')

data = data["a"]["b"]["location"]

print(data)
```

Comment: I understand this level of thinking in terms of filtering. I replaced 'a','b', with 'input' and 'results' and successfully printed the two coordinates...but how I do apply this to the entire json variable? Do I need to walk through the whole thing with a loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can also read you nested json file as a pandas DataFrame. Call your file `d` (that's the json file you gave in your question). Read it with

```
df = pd.json_normalize(d)
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.split(".")[-1])
```

Comment: This doesn't particularly help as the "results" column is not formatted at all and contains nested information. This is what I initially filtered using 'record_path' using addys = json_normalize(locations, record_path=['results']) --locations is the name of the json result